# Routing error for '/spreeapi'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, spree

I am testing spree locally and get the following error when attempting to choose product options:

```
Started GET "/spreeapi/option_types?q%5Bname_cont%5D=&_=1407867241807" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 13:14:04 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/spreeapi/option_types"):
```

Here is the relevant part of my `gemfile.lock`

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree/spree.git
  revision: 9d4617334c872e591839a930c2aa52c834ce0896
  branch: 2-3-stable
  specs:
    spree (2.3.2.beta)
      spree_api (= 2.3.2.beta)
```

And `routes.rb`

```
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the beta. I would suggest using a stable version. Someone may have misspelled the path or the like.

Comment: I don't get it those are the specs for branch: 2-3-stable ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try /spree/api instead of /spreeapi? I don't see any routes available for spreeapi in the default spree applications.

Comment: No idea where this is coming from. I had to create a custom route

Comment: is this site local or public? would I be able to view it?